# ubuntu 9.10 minimal install vm cannot mount iso9660

Tags: linux

I cannot mount ISOs after installing Ubuntu 9.10 server minimal install.

> unknown filesystem type 'iso9660'

I've been searching the web for a while, without any solution. Hope someone can help.

Comment: This may be a known bug. See this link for a possible workaround (untested by me): https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-jeos/+bug/481267

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

1. get root (`sudo -i`)
2. load the module `modprobe iso9660`
3. try and mount (`mount -t iso9660 /dev/cdrom /mnt/cdrom`)